# "Enabling additional executable binary formats" fails

Tags: ubuntu, boot

On ubuntu 14.04, after doing `do-release-upgrade -d` several systems failed like dbus, network-manager, sound card etc.. I am logged into terminal instead of X.

Looking at the `/var/log/boot.log` I managed to fix all failed services except the line "enabling additional executable binary formats". What is the purpose of it and how do I debug it?

Comment: That is related to binfmt-support, I believe. What are the error messages? Does the service fail to start?

Comment: Yes, the service fails, I don't even know what it is used for or how to debug it. I don't even know what is the name of the service that is responsible for that line. Thanks for the hint, I will look into it.

Comment: You were right - reinstalling `binfmt-support` fixed this issue. Thanks.

Comment: @schaiba You should post an answer stating that this message comes from `binfmt-support`, as this was the blocking hurdle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"enabling additional executable binary formats" is a message that originates from `binfmt-support`. As seen above, reinstalling said service is the way to go.